# Magento: Change the block template in local.xml

Tags: magento

I would like the product reviews page to use a different template instead of:

**catalog/product/view.phtml**

In **review.xml**, I see the file being called:

```
<block type="review/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

Is there a way I can override that in local.xml and create a new file (ex: view2.phtml) and use that for this page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<review_product_list>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view2.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</review_product_list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely do that by writing the following code in `local.xml`:-

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view2.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Here `view2.phtml` is your new file in the proper folder structure.

Hope it helps.